# Bleed Damage vs. Fast Healing / Regeneration?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Going by this question: [Is Bleed worth optimizing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48691/is-bleed-worth-optimizing)

Fast Heal will allow a creature to clean up bleed damage quickly, but my question is does it do any damage on the first round before healing kicks in? Or does the opponent get to choose the order.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Bleed) :

> A creature that is taking bleed damage takes the listed amount of damage at the beginning of its turn.

There is nothing specified for [Fast Healing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Fast-Healing-Ex-) so I would assume the creature takes bleed damage first then heal.